# import { TOKEN } from '@env'

Tags: reactjs, .env

I am working on an app with React Js and I am in the midst of using an API key, that I have to hide. I have created a ".env" file in the root of my project to store the key, however, when I try to import it on App.js it provides me with an error stating,
"@env could not be found within the porject or in these directories:
node_modules
../../../node_modules"

Here is how I try to import the TOKEN (.env) on App.js
`import { TOKEN } from '@env'`

I also had to download the following in my terminal;
`npm install -D react-native-dotenv`

.env
`TOKEN=************`

I tries to move around the file yet nothing happend. I am positive the file is in the root of my project.

Comment: you should use a relative path like `../.env` instead of `@env`. If you want to use `@env`, you need to set it up first, which you seemed to have missed.

Answer (score 1):

In React, any environment variable that got loaded will be found under

```
process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

where the variable would be in your .env file like

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=hello
```

Note the use of the prefix `REACT_APP` to allow them to be exposed. You don't have to do anything specific for them to be loaded except respecting this naming. However, if your concern is to not show these variables, **DO NOT USE THE ENV TO STORE THEM**. They would get embedded at compile time thus ending up visible in your code. Please refer to the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) for more details.

If your concern is to safely store some keys, I would redirect you to solutions such as storing these in your backend, or using services such as [AWS Key Management Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html) or [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/key-vault) to give you the most common ones.

An alternative solution is to use [server injection](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags#injecting-data-from-the-server-into-the-page) as described in the docs, which means replacing parts of the code within the server to not expose the values.